# Is there only one set of nontrivial solutions to this Diophantine equation?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=6d^3$$
Since $(a,b,c)$ is symmetrical, let's assume $a<b<c$ and $d>0$.

Is there only one set of (nontrivial) nonzero integer solutions to this Diophantine equation?
$$\left(a,b,c,d\right)=\left(-1,2,5,3\right)$$

Note that these solutions $\left(a,b,c,d\right)=\left(-8,-5,-5,-3\right),\left(4,7,7,3\right),\left(5,5,8,3\right)$ etc are **not** considered.

Comment: I have already given you the formula for finding such numbers.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049581___

Comment: @individ . Thank you, but I'm not sure that's all the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above equation shown below:

x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=6d^3 ----(1)

In Individ solution take (a,b,k,t)=(98,21,3,5) we get

(x,y,z,d)=(184,190,214,42)

So the answer to "OP" question is negative. There

are multiple solutions to equation (1).

Comment: Thanks, this solution can be reduce to $(a,b,c,d)=(92, 95, 107, 21)$.

Comment: @Eufisky. You are welcome. Equation (1)  can be generalized for rhs equal to kd^3. For k=1 solution is already known & I think for some other 'k' parametric solution can be arrived at.